# Append text at the end of first column. Notepad++ or macro on text file

Tags: notepad++

How do i do that in Notepad++ ?
Adding .USA for first column only ?

```
AABA,D,20180323,74.98,75.75,72.67,73,5051300
AAL,D,20180323,52.63,53.1,50.99,51.01,3966000
AAME,D,20180323,3.13,3.25,3.1,3.25,1100
```

Results:

```
AABA.USA,D,20180323,74.98,75.75,72.67,73,5051300
AAL.USA,D,20180323,52.63,53.1,50.99,51.01,3966000
AAME.USA,D,20180323,3.13,3.25,3.1,3.25,1100
```

Comment: macro record it like: go to beginning of 1st line, start record macro, find comma, go back one character, type ".USA", go to beginning of line,  fo down, stop macro recording and then press and hold you selected key combo for the new recorded macro till you get to the end of file. not a pretty solution, but it works, used macros for such operations a lot of times as they were usually needed only once.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ doesn't understand lookbehind, you have to use `\K` instead.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^,]+\K`
- Replace with: `.USA`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
[^,]+   : 1 or more any character that is not a comma
\K      : forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Result for given example:**

```
AABA.USA,D,20180323,74.98,75.75,72.67,73,5051300
AAL.USA,D,20180323,52.63,53.1,50.99,51.01,3966000
AAME.USA,D,20180323,3.13,3.25,3.1,3.25,1100
```